# Need a regex using Regular expression in Notepad++ for the replacing of one word per line

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

not long ago someone gave me the regex to replace a list of places for Missouri with the same pattern like this in which I wanted to replace (in Spanish) to **|[[X (Misuri)|X]] || ciudad || 00** , where "city" was translated to "ciudad" in Spanish, where "X" is the name of the city, and "0" the population:
From this

> **Acacia Villas city 427**

to this:

> **|[[Acacia Villas (Misuri)|Acacia Villas]] || ciudad || 427**

This was the regex that I used to replace those lines as shown above.

> **Search: (.*)\scity\s(.*)**
>
> **Replace: |[[\1 (Misuri)|\1]] || ciudad**

Now, I tried to modified the regex for the replacing for another list of places in Vermont (and other states), but i couldn't create the Regex,

The list goes like this: But this time i want to translate the county into Spanish and I want to eliminate 'town' just the one that are in lower cases and County in order to translate it to Spanish.

> Andover town, Tolland County 3,303
>
> Ansonia town, New Haven County    19,249
>
> Ashford town, Windham County  4,317
>
> Avon town, Hartford County    18,098
> etc..

At the end each line should look like this, can anyone help me? :

**|[[Andover (Vermont)|Andover]] || [[condado de Tolland (Vermont)|Tolland]] || 3,303**

Another question, there is another list that i want to replace this time they are townships in Arkansas, and im not sure if the same regex for the towns will work for them, so im just gonna ask for the regex now just in case, eliminating the word township and County where Municipio is township in Spanish. Thank you!

**For: Acorn township, Polk County 1,503**

> To: **|[[Municipio de Acorn (condado de Polk, Arkansas)|Acorn]] || [[condado de Polk (Arkansas)|Polk]] || 1,503**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Search: (.*)\town,\s(.*)\Country\s(.*)
Replace: |[[\1 (Vermont)|\1]] || [[condado de \2 (Vermont)|\2]] || \3
```

```
Search: (.*)\township,\s(.*)\Country\s(.*)
Replace: |[[Municipio de \1 (condado de \2, Arkansas)|\1]] || [[condado de \2 (Arkansas)|\2]] || \3
```